# fwrite doesn't break the line

Tags: php, string, newline, fwrite

I'm writing this:

```
 $fh = fopen('public/newsletter.txt', 'w');
 foreach($entries as $row) {
        fwrite($fh, 'e-mail\n');
        fwrite($fh, $row->new_email . ';');
 }
 fclose($fh);
```

Expecting it to be

```
email
email@example.com;
```

But I'm getting

```
e-mail\nemail@example.com;
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use double quotes in place of single quotes.

```
fwrite($fh, "e-mail\n");
            ^        ^
```

The char combination `\n` is treated as a newline when it's inside double quotes. But when inside single quotes it's not treated and letter `\` followed by `n`.

Comment: i agree with that. but i have one addition: depengin on the OS you are using you might have to consider using \r and/or \n\r

Comment: in Windows it is now printing `e-mailemail@example.com;`

Comment: try using `\r\n` in place of `\n'